# php changing the value of an item inside a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a problem I am working on where I need to loop through 2 different arrays and change the value of the items in the second array.  For some reason the code below will loop through both arrays and change the value to the second array but when I go the retrieve the values from the second array again they are set back to zero.  Anyone know what is going on here or what I might be doing wrong?

```
<?php
 $list1 = array(    array("item1", 1),
                array("item2", 1),
                array("item3", 2),
                array("item4", 6));


 $list2 = array(    array("CHF", 0),
                array("HF", 0),
                array("AMI", 0),
                array("COPD", 0),
                array("PN", 0),
                array("THA", 0),
                array("TKA", 0));

 foreach( $list1 as $stuff ) {
    foreach( $list2 as $val ) {
        $val[1] = $val[1] + 1;
    }
 }

 foreach( $list2 as $poo ) {            
    echo "<br/>" . $poo[0] . " = " . $poo[1];
 }
?>
```

this outputs the following

CHF=0,HF=0,AMI=0,COPD=0,PN=0,THA=0,TKA=0

But what I want it to output is:

CHF=1,HF=1,AMI=1,COPD=1,PN=1,THA=1,TKA=1

Comment: its not clear at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the loop value [assign-by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead of value in the `foreach` loop, as follows:

```
 foreach( $list1 as &$stuff ) {
    foreach( $list2 as &$val ) {
        $val[1] = $val[1] + 1;
    }
 }
```

If you assign by value, you are getting and modifying copies of the elements, which are then discarded. That's why the original array is left untouched.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You have no idea how long I was working on this.  Cant believe it was simple as adding an "&" symbol...lol

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you should pass your second array by the reference. Simply add & to its name in second foreach loop. Your variant is operating on copy of array. In addition it's necessary to reorganize your code a bit. Just now it will increase each value in second array four times because code for each element from inner array will run for every iteration from outer array.